# Internal Salesforce.com Error on CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE or LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS

Tags: apex, soql, exception

**Issue**: I'm experiencing a Fatal Error - Internal Salesforce.com Error while running a query that could be possibly be returning a huge number or records. Any thoughts on how to resolve this?

Originating context: UI - lwc component

**Error Log Snippet:**

```
SYSTEM_METHOD_ENTRY|[150]|Database.countQuery(String)
SOQL_EXECUTE_BEGIN|[150]|Aggregations:0|SELECT count() FROM Task WHERE Some_criteria_r.Filter = null AND RecordType.DeveloperName = 'RecordTypeName'
LIMIT_USAGE|[150]|SOQL|2|100
LIMIT_USAGE|[150]|AGGS|1|300
FATAL_ERROR|Internal Salesforce.com Error
CUMULATIVE_LIMIT_USAGE
LIMIT_USAGE_FOR_NS|(default)|
Number of SOQL queries: 2 out of 100
Number of query rows: 3 out of 50000
```

**Method Executed:**

```
   public static String queryMethod(Id someId)
    {
        CustomObject__c record = [
            SELECT Object__c,
                (SELECT Field_Path__c, Operator__c, Value__c, Values__c FROM Criteria__r)
            FROM CustomObject__c
            WHERE Id = :someId
        ];
        return 'SELECT count() FROM ' +
            String.escapeSingleQuotes(record.Object__c) +
            ' WHERE ' + buildWhereClause(record.Criteria__r);
    }
```

Comment: I ran into a problem that I think is similar to this one. If you're getting an error just getting count() on an object, my hunch is that there are several millions of these Task__c records. And since they're tasks, it sounds like that may be the case. 

The problem I ran into was that adding any filter conditions, especially when the fields weren't indexed, made the query time out since it has to check every Task__c record.

Answer (score 2):

If you know that this query might be returning a huge amount of records, it might be a good idea to take a step back and see if you can limit more your query (adding more criteria) so that it doesn't return many records. If that is not possible, then you have to take another step back and see if you can tackle this some other way, such as using methods such as pagination using `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.